# "Argument path does not exist or is not accessible" when trying to find a file in share folder

Tags: ansible, path, drive, shared-directory

After connecting to share folder \10.14.2.130\shared\ , I am trying to search for files in 'Data' folder inside the share folder.

```
  - name: Search for files in Data folder
    win_find:
      paths: \\10.14.2.130\shared\folder\Data\
    register: file1
```

The task is supposed to show that there is a file in the folder.
However, this was the error I got:

```
**[WARNING]: Argument path '\\10.14.2.130\shared\folder\Data\' does not exist or is not accessible, skipping**
ok: [10.12.201.60] => {
    "changed": false,
    "examined": 0,
    "files": [],
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "age": null,
            "age_stamp": "mtime",
            "checksum_algorithm": "sha1",
            "file_type": "file",
            "follow": false,
            "get_checksum": true,
            "hidden": false,
            "paths": [
                "\\\\10.14.2.130\\shared\\folder\\Data\\"
            ],
            "patterns": null,
            "recurse": false,
            "size": null,
            "use_regex": false
        }
    },
    "matched": 0
}
```

However, when I run the same task on the share folder host itself (10.14.2.130), it manages to output the result that there is a file in the folder:

```
ok: [10.14.2.130] => {
    "changed": false,
    "examined": 1,
    "files": [
        {
            "attributes": "Archive",
            "checksum": "141a1f8872be45d532973c56688cf800700b01bb",
            "creationtime": 1678294890.4031632,
            "exists": true,
            "extension": ".csv",
            "filename": "sample.csv",
            "hlnk_targets": [],
            "isarchive": true,
            "isdir": false,
            "ishidden": false,
            "isjunction": false,
            "islnk": false,
            "isreadonly": false,
            "isreg": true,
            "isshared": false,
            "lastaccesstime": 1678294890.4031632,
            "lastwritetime": 1677091528,
            "lnk_source": null,
            "lnk_target": null,
            "nlink": 1,
            "owner": "BUILTIN\\Administrators",
            "path": "\\\\10.14.2.130\\shared\\folder\\Data\\sample.csv",
            "sharename": null,
            "size": 949
        }
    ],
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "age": null,
            "age_stamp": "mtime",
            "checksum_algorithm": "sha1",
            "file_type": "file",
            "follow": false,
            "get_checksum": true,
            "hidden": false,
            "paths": [
                "\\\\10.14.2.130\\shared\\folder\\Data\\"
            ],
            "patterns": null,
            "recurse": false,
            "size": null,
            "use_regex": false
        }
    },
    "matched": 1
```

How can I make host 10.12.201.60  properly search for a file in \\10.14.2.130\shared\folder\Data\ ?

Edit: I used this task to connect to share folder:

```
  - name: Connect to shared folder
    win_command: 'net use Z: \\10.14.2.130\shared\ /user:username passwordhere /p:yes'
    become: yes
    become_method: runas
    become_user: SYSTEM
```

I have checked and found out that it shows up as a disconnected drive in file explorer, but I could still click on it to see the files inside.
Is ansible unable to find the share folder path because the drive is disconnected? How do I use Ansible to connect to the drive successfully so that it can search for files inside the share folder?

Comment: Hi Blitzden welcome to SO. As a distinction, I would guess \\ references on the same machine do not need authentication, whereas the user the task is running under may not have permissions to access the remote server; have you already confirmed it can, by (for example) issuing a `NET USE` in a prior task to mount that UNC path as a drive? It's important to know exactly what is and is not happening.

Comment: Hi mdaniel, thank you.
I have updated the post and added the net use task that I used to connect to the drive. I just checked and found out that the drive shows up as disconnected. I think this might be the cause of the issue? 
Is there a way to use Ansible to connect to the drive properly?

Comment: Well, that `become_user: SYSTEM` would need to be applied to the `win_find:` also, since the whole theory we're troubleshooting is whether the user the ansible task is running as has enough permissions to access the share on the other computer. Further, did you use `/user:{{ ansible_user }}` in order to ensure the credential it used to map the drive is the one the playbook normally runs as, or you used some random username?

Comment: Hi mdaniel, sorry for the late reply. I was away + my server had some network issues so I wasn't able to test your suggestion earlier. It is partially correct, I had to add these 3 things to the win_find task:   
  become: yes, become_method: runas, become_user: SYSTEM

/user: {{ username }} is the username to log in to 10.14.2.130; where the share folder is originally created.

Comment: Don't forget you can [post and accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to let others know what solution you found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task was able to produce the correct output after I input become, become_method, and become_user in win_find task:

```
- name: Search for files in Data folder
  win_find:
    paths: \\10.14.2.130\shared\folder\Data\
  register: file1
  become: yes
  become_method: runas
  become_user: SYSTEM
```